# Find the tight bound for the following.

Tags: recurrence-relations

Find a tight bound for the following recurrence.

$$T(1) = 2$$
$$T(n) = T(\frac{n}{3}) + 4n$$

Using the master's theorem, I have:

$$ 1 > \log{_3}{1}$$

$$k > \log{_b}{a}$$

Thus, I can conclude that $T(n) = O(n^k)$

The problem is that this seems conflicting with what I've found using substitution method.

$k = 1$
$$T(n) = T(\frac{n}{3}) + 4n$$
$k = 2$
$$T(n) = T(\frac{n}{9}) + 8n$$
$k = 3$
$$T(n) = T(\frac{n}{27}) + 12n$$
$k = 4$
$$T(n) = T(\frac{n}{81}) + 16n$$

Guessing the recurrence, I get the following

$$T(n) = T(\frac{n}{3^k}) + 4kn$$

At the base case, $\frac{n}{3^k} = 1$, thus, $n = 3^k$, and therefore, $ k = \log{_3}{n}$

Then, we have

$$T(n) = T(1) + 4n\log{_3}{n}$$
$$T(n) = 2 + 4n\log{_3}{n}$$

Doing some calculations, I can conclude that $T(n) = \theta(n\log{_3}{n})$. This causes conflict with the answer I reached from the master's theorem.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The Master theorem would give $\Theta(n \log n)$ here: you are in [Case 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_2). ($a=1$, $b=3$, $c=\log_b a =0$, and $k=0$)

Comment: I thought $4n = \theta(n^1)$? Thus in this case $k = 1$?

Comment: Look at the exact statement of the theorem. For the "first case" to apply, you would need $f(n) = O(n^c)$ for $c < \log_b a = 0$...

Comment: Ah. Apologies, i seem to have misunderstood the usage of master's theorem.

Comment: Wait, actually, if I am in case 2, how can I have both $c = 0$ and $k=0$ both. Don't you think I will need $c= 1$? If both are 0, then I would have $4n = \theta(1)$. Which is certainly false.

Comment: You're right, I wrote too fast: it looks like here, you are in the third case, and the answer should be $\Theta(n)$ (i.e., you substitution approach was erroneous as well). To doublecheck, though -- it's late. (but something like $T(n) = 6n-5$ looks reasonable)

Comment: One last thing. $f(n) = 4n$ Since we have the third case, it follows that $f(n) = \theta(4n)$, does this always mean that $f(n) = \theta(n)$?

Comment: You never put multiplicative constants in big-Oh notations: they are meant to "hide" these constants. (Look at the definition of the notation itself: one of the very points is to focus on the order of growth, ignoring the multiplicative constants.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31654/discussion-between-thevalars-and-clement-c).